# How to get query params using Server component (next 13)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Next13 is out, and they advise to use the new `app` directory where every component is by default a ["Server Component"](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#server-components)

Inside a "server Component", you can use:

- `async/await` to fetch data.
- `cookies()` to retrieve cookies
- `headers()` to retrieve request headers.

**But I can't find how to retrieve query params.**

Before Next 13, within `getServerSideProps`, you could use `context.query` to access the query params.

**Do you know how to retrieve query params using "server Component" in Next 13.**

Comment: I am not aware of any method to do that for now. I have been looking for a method as well but haven't gotten any luck. I only know of useSearchParams and that is for client-side components. Were you able to find a way and how did you do that?

Comment: I didn't find a solution for this so far

Answer (score 129, accepted):

I don't think it's currently possible to do this in an arbitrary component. However, it is possible to access query parameters in `page.tsx` files, and pass these down to your components via props.

```
export default function Page({
  params,
  searchParams,
}: {
  params: { slug: string };
  searchParams?: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}) {
  return <h1>{searchParams?.greeting || "Hello!"}</h1>;
}
```

See the [Docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/page)

Comment: That sounds like a good workaround.

Comment: Awesome, using `searchParams` is work for me. thanks.

Comment: Sadly this makes Partial Prerendering (PPR) impossible to use to scope using searchParams to a specific dynamic component, the whole page has to be dynamic, or you need a client component + "useSearchParams" hook

Answer (score 10):

I know this is going to sound bad but I have not found anything either, so you will have to parse it out yourself

here is an example

```
import type { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import qs from 'qs';
export async function GET(request: NextRequest, response: NextResponse) {
   try {
      const rawParams = request.url.split('?')[1];
      const params = qs.parse(rawParams);
// Now you have access to the query String parameters //
// Or you can do it this way
      const yourParamName = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get('paramName');
// also try getAll() I think that might work
    } catch (error: unknown) {
      console.log(error);
   }
}
```

Comment: In routes you can use `req.nextUrl.searchParams` which returns `URLSearchParams`. You get get a specific param by  `req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("paramName")`.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I found an easy way to get Query Value in Next.js 13.4.

Example `route.ts` file:

```js
export async function GET(request: Request) {

    const url = new URL(request.url);
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
    const skip = searchParams.get("skip"); // Retrieves the value of the 'skip' parameter
    const limit = searchParams.get("limit"); // Retrieves the value of the 'limit' parameter

    console.log(skip);
    console.log(limit);

    return new Response(JSON.stringify({message: "Hello World"}), {status: 200});
}
```

Comment: hmm, where exactly is the `request` variable coming from? I dont see it in scope for app router/Nextjs

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works in routes where you have access to the `request` object (as Nishant already explained above).

Comment: export const  POST = (request) =>{}

Comment: getting Error:
Invalid  URL

Comment: This works for me, thanks. Gonna edit a little bit because people cannot understand it's an app router mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to access the URL search params without having to pass them down, you might want to use middleware to set the URL in the request headers and get that in your server component.

```
// /middleware.ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export default function middleware(request: NextRequest, event: NextFetchEvent) {
  request.headers.set('x-url', request.url);

  return next(request, event);
}
```

Then, in any server component:

```
import { headers } from 'next/headers';

export const ServerComponent = () => {
  const url = new URL(headers().get('x-url')!);
  const searchParams = url.searchParams;
  // ...
}
```

Also see https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43704#issuecomment-1411186664

Comment: headers() is a Dynamic Function whose returned values cannot be known ahead of time. Using it will opt a route into dynamic rendering at request time. Check out: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#dynamic-rendering

Answer (score 1):

> NextJS version - 13.5.2

File location PROJECT/src/app/api/products/route.js

```
export async function GET(request) {

    const queryString = request.url.split('?')[1];
    const page = Number(new URLSearchParams(queryString).get('page')) || 1;
    const limit = Number(new URLSearchParams(queryString).get('limit')) || 1;

    console.log(page)
    console.log(limit)

    return NextResponse.json({ 'status': true }, { status: 200 })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a combination of everything mentioned here.
As a set of functions you can put in a lirary and import as needed.
These will work on client and server

```
export const parseHeaders = (request: Request) => {
    let headers = {};
    for (let [name, value] of request.headers.entries()) {
        headers[name] = value;
    }
    return headers;
};
export const parseQuery = (request: Request) => {
    const url = new URL(request.url);
    const query = parseSearchParams(url);
    return query;
};
export const parseSearchParams = (url: URL) => {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
    let data = {};
    for (let [name, value] of searchParams.entries()) {
        data[name] = value;
    }
    return data;
};
export const parseRequest = (request: Request) => {
    let query = parseQuery(request);
    let headers = parseHeaders(request);
    return { query, headers };
};
```

in a route,

```
export async function GET(request: Request) {
    const { headers, query } = parseRequest(request);
```

in a client component without having to pass down props,

```
export function Component() {
    const query = parseSearchParams(window.location);
}
```

Comment: This is a route handler not `server component`

Comment: I clearly said "These will work on client *and* server" followed by examples "in a route,". My sample is re-usable and might be helpful to some.