# How do I get the exact query string in nextjs 14 app router on the server?

Tags: next.js

When using app router, how do I get the exact query string on the server? I now I can use the `searchParams` property to get the object version of the search params, but I would like the exact query string as you get when calling `useSearchParams` on the client.

Comment: Not on the server-side, unless you let your server pages to be dynamically rendered by using your middleware to inject a dynamic header on request, and read that header in your server components. Is there a reason this cannot be offloaded to a client component that has access to `useSearchParams`, or access it via `page.tsx` and then prop-drill it down?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get query params using Server component (next 13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74889841/how-to-get-query-params-using-server-component-next-13)

Comment: @Terry, thanks for your reply. I think I can use `useSearchParams` after all since it will be accessible on the first render on the server as well. The reason why I can't prop-drill the properties is because I wanted the exact string to use as a key to swr.